# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again in Eclipse -Maven project-Windows 11

Tags: eclipse, testng, unsupported-class-version

In my Eclipse photon version 2018 try to execute my code using TestNG while facing this error.

Kindly refer the error at my console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/TestNGException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Created the Maven project and add the required dependencies `Selenium-java 3.141.59`,`testng 6.14.3`,`poi 5.0.0`,`poi-ooxml 5.0.0` and try to run my code at src/test/java it shows the error and exception.

Hence I tried to change JDK version as 11.0.10 even verified in command prompt which shows java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS. And I make the changes in environment variable that system variable path as **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin** . After I try to change build path in JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] as JRE 11th version in Alternate JRE but couldn't.

Comment: What JRE is selected in the Run Configuration that runs this code in Eclipse? Have you told Eclipse about the Java 11 in the "Java > Installed JREs" in the Preferences? Also note that Eclipse Photon is now 4 years and 17 releases old.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In Alternate JRE I have selected jre 1.8.0_301 and it is the one option available . yes I told about java 11. what version you preferred me to install?

Comment: Photon did not support Java 11--it was released in the middle of 2018. You need a newer version. There have already been 16 releases of Eclipse since then.

Comment: ok. got your point. Currently I am using java 1.8 and run the program still facing same error " java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/TestNGException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"

Comment: That code is compiled for Java 11 and will **not** run with Java 8, you must move to at least Java 11 to run it.